# Combo box Default Text

Tags: c#-4.0

I have a combo box that shows data from a (list) datasource. I want to show a text in the combo box as the first of the items, showing  "-ALL-". How can I do this?

I am working on windows form applicaiton.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`combo1.Text="All"`

Comment: it works when the datasource list is string..but my datasource list is another type..let it's like lst<medicine>....in this case..how can i show it?